# Strftime of datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, strftime

I got the below code which I would like to convert to a string in a specific format. But I can't get it working.

```
Date.today + warning.notify_time_close.seconds
```

What I want to do is somethin like this but it doesn't work :)

```
(Date.today + warning.notify_time_close.seconds).strftime "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

I know its simple but just don't know how to do it :)

Thanks in advance!

Kenneth

Comment: What does `warning.notify_time_close` return?  If it's an int then the above should work.  I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: If you do `Date.today + 3` it adds three days, not three seconds

Comment: Its an int.. and it works in the console.. but im using it in an RSS builder.. It get this error: undefined method `strftime' for #<String:0x103432430>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should not be necessary, but as a workaround you could try this:

```
Time.at(
    Date.today.to_time.to_i + warning.notify_time_close.seconds
).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Doesn't work either.. :) Still gets an error: undefined method `strftime' for #<String:0x103629d38>

Comment: Well then `warning.notify_time_close.seconds` is a `String` somehow... what happens if you try `warning.notify_time_close.seconds.to_i`?

Comment: Still the same.. Even get the error if i replace warning.notify_time_close with 100.. Its all going on in a feed.rss.builder file - could that be an issue?

Comment: This one works: Date.today.to_time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").. But doesn't give me the right result..

Comment: I posted a workaround.. not sure why the stuff in the braces get converted to a `String`